# How to synthesize members from another class

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch

I have created a certain class to represent an object. My program has several views and view controllers. I want the different view controllers to work with this object. However, when I try to synthesize the class members so that they can be used in the view controller, I get an error saying that there is no declaration of the property found in the interface, even after I have included the .h file. How can I synthesize members from another class in the various view controllers that will be working with them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without seeing your code or the specific compiler errors, it's hard to say what might be going on.

If you're just setting up a simple model object, then you should be able to write something like this in `Model.h`:

```
@interface Model : NSObject {}

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *name;

@end
```

and in your `Model.m` file:

```
@implementation Model

@synthesize name;

@end
```

All you need to do at that point is `#import "Model.h"` into your other source files and then you can use the `name` property like so:

```
Model *m = [[Model alloc] init];
m.name = @"Bob";
...
```

It sounds like the compiler is complaining about the lack of the `@property` declaration in your case.

Comment: I am creating the property I just didn't write anything in the m file. That was the problem.